# How do you configure your terminal env to work with ROS/PR2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After hearing/reading the question from Morgan I thought to ask around for the tips&tricks you are using in setting up your "terminal comfort zone".

Next to my regular bash_aliases I carry the following ones in my .bash_aliases file:

```
alias roslatest='source /opt/ros/latest/setup.sh'
alias rosunstable='source /opt/ros/unstable/setup.bash' 
alias rosboxturtle='source /opt/ros/boxturtle/setup.sh'
alias roscturtle='source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.bash'
alias rosdiamondback='source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash'

alias rospath='export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/koen/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'
alias roslocal='export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311'
alias rospr2='export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pma-robot-rubens1:11311'
alias rosamigo='export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://amigo1:11311'

alias rosdashboard='rosrun pr2_dashboard pr2_dashboard'
alias tuckarm='rosrun pr2_tuckarm tuckarm.py b'
alias teleop='roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_joystick.launch'
alias teleopkey='roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch'
alias rviz='rosrun rviz rviz'

# This adds the route to the lab
alias pr2route='sudo route add -net 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.33.175.57'

alias xacro='rosrun xacro xacro.py'
alias tilthorizontal='rosrun pr2_mechanism_controllers send_periodic_cmd.py laser_tilt_controller linear 1 0 0'
alias tiltscan='rosrun pr2_mechanism_controllers send_periodic_cmd.py laser_tilt_controller linear 4 1 0'
alias facedetector='roslaunch face_detector face_detector.wide.launch'
alias teleopbooth='roslaunch pr2_teleop_booth pr2_teleop_booth.launch'

alias rosenv='env | grep ROS'
alias rossim='export ROBOT=sim'
alias rosreal='export ROBOT=pr2'
```

I assume the bash wizards among us must have created some more fancy onces, these are mainly to cut down on the typing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9449/how-do-you-configure-your-terminal-env-to-work-with-ros/pr2/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From GeniousGeeko:

delete ROS log files older than 5 days:

```
echo "find ~/.ros/log/* -mtime +5 -exec rm -r {} \;" >> ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0